# Get focus on a tab of jquery UI tabs

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

I would like to give focus on the tab with the href tabs_11 :

```
<div id="tabs">

            <!-- PB :: MENU_PRINCIPAL_________________________________________________-->
            <ul>
                <!--<li><a href="#tabs_2-1">Mes données personnelles</a></li>-->
                <li><a href="#tabs_2-4">Mes stagiaires</a></li>
                <li><a href="#tabs_2-2">Formulaire d'évaluation</a></li>

                <!--<li><a href="#tabs_2-3">Mon calendrier</a></li>-->
                <li><a href="#tabs-1">Personnel</a></li>

                <li><a href="#tabs-6">Documentation</a></li>
                <!--<li><a href="#tabs-7">Equipement IT</a></li>-->
                <li><a href="#tabs-8">Motivation</a></li>
                <li><a href="#tabs_9">Mon calendrier</a></li>
                <li><a href="#tabs_10">Documents utiles & FAQ</a></li>
                <li><a href="#tabs_11">Renouveler mon agrément</a></li>

            </ul>


            <?php
        if(isset($_SESSION['en_attente']) && isset($_SESSION['soumis']))
        {
                ?>
                  <script>


                        alert("Message");

                        $('#tabs_11').tabs(
                        {
                                active: index
                        });

                 </script>

        <?php 
        }
?>
```

This code does not allow me to select the tab with the href #tabs_11

I tried everything, no success...

Comment: The code part where the tab defined would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

```
   $('#tabs_11').tabs(
```

In jQuery # means element ID, it's not the same as a # in a URL string. Give your li/a element an ID, or access it based on a different property, like href for example:

```
$( "a[href='#tabs_11']" ).closest("li"); // if you need to target the li element
$( "a[href='#tabs_11']" ) // if you dont
```